# print quotes only if value exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to enclose values in double quotes, but only if a value is selected.

I have this, for example

```
select '"'||name||'"'
from table;
```

When a name value is selected this works fine - `"Joe"`.

But if a record has no name value, then I get `""`

How can I conditionally display the double quotes only when a value is selected?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out with a CASE statement.

```
select case when name is not null then '"'||name||'"' else NULL end
from table
```